# My code doesn't continue until the program open by subprocess is closed

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use the Subprocess module to open a notepad, then print that the program was opened.
My code:

```
import os
import subprocess
if os.path.exists(r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'):
    subprocess.run(r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')
    print('Program executed')
```

Notepad opens, but the problem is that the print command doesn't work until I close Notepad. is there anyway to overcome this?

Comment: `subprocess.run()` blocks until the command finishes. Use threads, multiprocessing or any of the async options (or detach the command you're running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Popen instead of run helps. Then the script doesn't wait for the program is closed:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')
```